# COmo hacer que matriz magica se llene sola avanzando una columna y bajando dos filas

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente caso, lo que sucede es que me plantearon un ejercicio que debe hacer lo siguiente, debe ser un menú donde tenga dos opciones, una donde cree una matriz magica de manera automática y otra donde el usuario la llene y simplemente se valide si es magica o no, el problema que tengo es con crear la matriz de manera automatica, ya que debo seguir los siguientes paso:

1. solicitar a un usuario un numero impar para definir el tamño de la matriz cuadrada.
2. Colocar el numero 1 en la mitad d ela matriz
3. validar si el numero colocado es multiplo del numero dado por el usuario, si lo llega a ser colocar el numero que sigue en la misma columna pero una fila abajo es decir debajo de el.
4. Si no llega a ser multiplo de este, avanzar una **columna** y bajar **2 filas** y colocar el siguiente numero.

Al momento de llegar al tamaño de la matriz este no va a tener hacia donde continuar y va a salir que el problema es que no se puede colocar cosas fuera del tamaño de la matriz, entonces debe hacer lo siguiente, moverse lo que tenga que moverse, pero si llega al limite que vuelva al comienzo, por ejemplo si tiene que avanzar una columna pero no hay hacia donde entonces que vuelva hacia la primer columna, y en el caso de las filas entonces que cuente esos valores pero desde el comienzo de las filas.

No se como hacer para que haga ese proceso y se siga ejecutado mi código, este es el codigo:

package matriz.magica;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrizMagica {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escoge una opcion:");
    System.out.println("1. Crear matriz magica automaticamente");
    System.out.println("2. Que el usuario cree una matriz y comprobar si es magica o no");
    int opc = sn.nextInt();

    switch (opc) {
        case 1:

            System.out.println("Dime un numero impar: ");
            int n = sn.nextInt();
            int i_ant = 0;
            int j_ant = 0;

            int[][] matriz = new int[n][n];

            int num = 1; // numero que se va colocando en la matriz

            int i = 0;
            int j = n / 2; // Mitad de donde empezamos a llenar la matriz

            while (num != n * n) {
                matriz[i][j] = num;

                if (num % n == 0) {
                    i = i_ant + 1;
                    j = j_ant;
                    matriz[i][j] = num;
                }

                i_ant = i;
                j_ant = j;

                num++;
                j++;
                i = i + 2;

               
                for (int x = 0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                    for (int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                        System.out.print(matriz[x][y]);
                        if (y != matriz[x].length - 1) {
                            System.out.print("  ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("|");
                }
            }

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Dime un numero aleatorio impar");
            int f1 = 0;
            int c1 = 0;
            int matriz1[][] = new int[f1][c1];
            break;
    }

} //fin main }//fin clase
```

Y este es el resultado al ejecutarlo y seleccionar la primer opcion:

```
Escoge una opcion:
1. Crear matriz magica automaticamente
2. Que el usuario cree una matriz y comprobar si es magica o no
1
Dime un numero impar: 
3
|0  1  0|
|0  0  0|
|0  0  0|
|0  1  0|
|0  0  0|
|0  0  2|
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 3
    at matriz.magica.MatrizMagica.main(MatrizMagica.java:32)
C:\Users\Sebastian\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\16\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Sebastian\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\16\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Sebastian, bienvenido, creo que se soluciona, si cada vez que aumentas **`i`** o **`j`**, verificas si es mayor que **`n`** y de ser así, le restas **`n`**.  
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Hola como estas muchas gracias, ahorita le doy un recorrido, para responmderte mira que ya habia validado esa opcion ponia estos condicionales:
```
if (j >= n) {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    if (i >= n) {
                        i = i_ant - n;
                    }
```
Pero no me funciono me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Hola de nuevo, me equivoqué, debes poner **`> n -1`**.

Comment: Aprende a debuguear.. seguir linea a linea, ver el valor de tus variables.. con eso, vas a solucionar este y mil problemas mas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se me ocurre una opción con operadores ternarios para validar los puntos 3 y 4 de tu pregunta, quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
if (num % n == 0) { //Es multiplo, colocar el número que sigue en la misma columna pero una fila abajo es decir debajo de el
    i = i + 1 == n ? 0 : i + 1; //Si i+1,  iguala el valor de n, se pone 0
} else { // avanzar una columna y bajar 2 filas y colocar el siguiente numero.
    i = i + 2 == n ? 0 : i + 2 > n ? 1 : i + 2; //Si es igual a n se pone 0, si es mayor a n se pone 1, de lo contrario suma 2
    j = j + 1 == n ? 0 : j + 1;
}
```

El punto 2 ya lo tenías realizado, y el punto 1 no lo ví, pero te dejo una solución:

```
 if (n % 2 == 0 || n == 1) {
    System.out.println(n + " no es un número impar y distinto de 1");
    break;
}
```

También modifiqué un poco tu condición del while:

```
while (num <= n * n) {
```

Te comparto como queda el case completo.

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("Dime un numero impar: ");
    int n = sn.nextInt();

    if (n % 2 == 0 || n == 1) {
        System.out.println(n + " no es un número impar y distinto de 1");
        break;
    }

    int[][] matriz = new int[n][n];

    int num = 1; // numero que se va colocando en la matriz

    int i = 0;
    int j = n / 2; // Mitad de donde empezamos a llenar la matriz

    while (num <= n * n) {
        matriz[i][j] = num;

        if (num % n == 0) { //Es multiplo, colocar el número que sigue en la misma columna pero una fila abajo es decir debajo de el
            i = i + 1 == n ? 0 : i + 1; //Si i+1,  iguala el valor de n, se pone 0
        } else { // avanzar una columna y bajar 2 filas y colocar el siguiente numero.
            i = i + 2 == n ? 0 : i + 2 > n ? 1 : i + 2; //Si es igual a n se pone 0, si es mayor a n se pone 1, de lo contrario suma 2
            j = j + 1 == n ? 0 : j + 1;
        }

        num++;
        //Impresión de la matriz
        for (int x = 0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[x][y]);
                if (y != matriz[x].length - 1) {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
    }

    break;

case 2:
....
```

Te adjunto como quedaría sin usar el operador ternario:

```
if (num % n == 0) { //Es multiplo, colocar el número que sigue en la misma columna pero una fila abajo es decir debajo de el
    //i = i + 1 == n ? 0 : i + 1; //Si i+1,  iguala el valor de n, se pone 0
    if (i + 1 == n) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
} else { // avanzar una columna y bajar 2 filas y colocar el siguiente numero.
    //i = i + 2 == n ? 0 : i + 2 > n ? 1 : i + 2; //Si es igual a n se pone 0, si es mayor a n se pone 1, de lo contrario suma 2
    if (i + 2 == n) {
        i = 0;
    } else if (i + 2 > n) {
        i = 1;
    } else {
        i = i + 2;
    }

    //j = j + 1 == n ? 0 : j + 1;
    if (j + 1 == n) {
        j = 0;
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oye en serio muchas gracias no conocia los ternarios, es como una especie de condicional no?

Comment: Si, es un condicional, lo puedes reemplazar por un if-else.

Comment: Pero ese if- else dentro del else de si es multiplo o no, porque lo acabo de intentar y no me salio jajaja es que es dificil.

Comment: Ya pude jajajaj tube que poner que cuando aumenta en dos el condicional fuera que si i == n - 2

Comment: y si funciona bien?, te añadí a la respuesta como quedaría el cambio.